# How to block using a C++ namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

My code is including headers from some large open source projects. One of them is C and the other C++. Unfortunately, the C header declares structures that share the same name as C++ standard template library (std::) classes like `map` and `list`. I'm getting an "ambiguous symbol" error on those. It turns out that the C++ project has `using namespace std;` *in some header files*. I don't want to fork the packages and modify them if I can avoid it, as it would be a monumental task.

Is it possible instead to "turn off" the `using namespace std` inside my code, so it will not attempt to resolve `list` or `map` as possibly belonging to that namespace? See the code sample below and the needed `not_using` directive. I know `not_using` doesn't exist. I'm looking for a way to achieve that effect.

```
using namespace std;
map<string, string> mapOk; // compiles but conflicts with C symbol 

not_using namespace std;   // I need something like this because...
std::map<std::string, std::string> mapOk2; // I want to force the use of std:: to resolve
map<string, string> badMap;  // Causes compile error
```

Comment: File a bug with that C++ project (with patch to clean it up). That's terrible practice. (Unless you're (ab)using some sort of internal headers of theirs.)

Comment: There is no getting the cat back into the bag once it is out.  File an issue with the project and find a better one.